# Link table on many to many relation is not inserted in NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, nhibernate

I have the following classes:

```
Hotel: ID, ..., IList<Photo> Photos
Photo: ID, Url
```

and in the database the corresponding "Hotels" and "Photos" tables and a link table in between that contains the IDs :

```
HotelPhotos: HotelPhotoID, HotelID (linked to PK HotelID from Hotels table),  PhotoID (linked to PK PhotoID from Photos table)
```

The configuration file for Hotel class is :

```
...other fields mapped
<bag name="Photos" table="TravelRoutePhotos" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="false">
   <key column="TravelRouteID" />
   <many-to-many class="TravelAssistant.Model.HelperModels.Feedback.Photo" column="PhotoID"/>
</bag>
```

Whenever I add/update a hotel with a photo, I get correctly the inserted the Photo and Hotel data but the HotelPhotos table remains empty. 
I have tried flushing the session after updating, tried setting the "bag" to "idbag" in config file , removing the "inverse" from config file but stil the same result.

Could someone help me out please?

Tamas

**EDIT** The HotelPhoto class does not exist; only the link table HotelPhotos.

Comment: You talk about HotelPhotos, but the mapping you show is for Tags...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited my question. (I also had a tag field in my Hotel entity but the problem is the same for any link table).

Comment: do you have a bi-directional link between your objects? if so, you're probably not connecting the dots in the right way. can you post the code of how you add items to the bag collection?

Comment: The mapping still refers to a different table.

Comment: it is still `table="TravelRoutePhotos` which should be `table=HotelPhotos`

Answer (score 0):

Unclear whether you've edited incorrectly when changing your mapping, but from your code as it is your mapping entry should be

```
<bag name="Photos" table="HotelPhotos" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="false">
```

You also need to make sure that you're using `hotel.Photos.Add(photo);` or similar. You've definitely got the right idea about your mapping, and you shouldn't need the reference on Photo.hbm.xml so long as you don't want the Hotels collection in your Photo class.